# Notepad++ regular expression

Tags: notepad++

I want to remove this line from 1000 files. 
http://txt.do/52h7n

How to write a regular expression to do this?
Can anyone help?

Comment: what did you try and what line you want to remove?

Comment: Have you been hacked? You should wipe your website and restore from backup.

Comment: You are not looking for regular expressions because you lirerally know whot to remove from the files. You need any kind of loop that can iterate through your files and any script-like solution that can substitute a given string with an empty string. Basically, yes, all this can be done in NP++ if you can write scripts in it, but I guess you would not ask if you could.

Comment: Hi,,

I have in first line (1000 files) this 

<?php $ctbobo = [...................] ?><?php

Can I remove $ctbobo = [...................] ?><?php and leave first <?php 

??

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were to replace the text of the link itself and I did not click on it. Nevertheless, my hint is almost the same. If you already have a looping solution to iterate the files, then the rest will be easy with, just for example, awk for windows. If you insist on notepad, it will be just more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need to remove everything between `<?php` and `?>` without removing the PHP tags themselves?

Assuming the text is exactly the same in all files, you can use the following regular expression:

`<\?php \$ctbobo.*\$wwhipui-1;`

And then replace it with `<?php` (note the space at the end).

The result should be something like:

`<?php  ?>`

To do a batch search and replace in Notepad++ you need to press `Search` in menu, then `Find in files` or simply press `Ctrl+Shift+F`. After than you will need to select the folder that contains your files, filters (most likely you need "`*.php`"), insert regular expression from this post and then press `Find them all`. When it's done, you need to go to `Replace` tab in the same search dialog, insert replacing pattern from above and press `Replace all`.

I advise you to make a backup copy of all your files before making any batch updates.

Comment: Funny, I've written a couple of answers on the replace function of NP++ recently for which I started and checked the editor after a long while. And I could not recognize that Find in File tab although it's there and is really promising as the same function of the BIG IDE's. Lesson learnt. Thanks, glad I've been here.